# GNU support for extended inline assembler for cortex m7 double precision FPU

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

The GCC suite of programs provides an extended inline assembler constraint for single precision FPU code for Cortex M4 & M7 MPUs, so it is straightforward to code a check of FPU performance.

However this facility is not available for double precision FPUs (as available with Cortex M7) and extra coding is required. Is anyone aware of whether GNU is working on the provision of such a facility?

Comment: The best place to ask this question is gcc mailing list

Comment: Can you state the exact compiler version and options you are using, and an example of the code you would like to write?

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but the documentation says that the `w` constraint is unavailable on Thumb1, whereas the Cortex M4 and M7 should support Thumb2.  With `-mcpu=cortex-m4` the `w` constraint is accepted.  It seems to generate correct code at -O0 (https://godbolt.org/z/qneaqTdec) but at -O2 it emits a reference to an `s` register instead (https://godbolt.org/z/daTGEfv6G).  That seems like it might be a compiler bug.

Comment: Following [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84343), I tried using the (undocumented?) `P` modifier and that seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/zbh94dsEP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was being able to output a double return from my inline assembler. In the absence of the compiler recognising a double constraint (which GNU documents clearly as not being available on Thumb instructions) there was no apparent way of achieving this. However by inspecting the emitted assembler for double returning functions, I noticed that the compiler ALWAYS moves the D7 register to the D0 register (as one of its last instructions) and D0 is of course a function's output register by convention. So I modified my code to use the D7 register to store my returned double and, it works!

Subsequent to the above, Nate Eldridge drew my attention to an undocumented GCC modifier (%P) in association with the (documented but not supposed to work with THUMB instructions) "w" constraint. The double precision code now works. Interestingly, when using the %P modifier the compiler emits D7 as its choice of register for the DP arithmetic; the subsequent move of D7 to D0 remains, but this time to good effect.

Comment: This is probably not a reliable solution.  Maybe the compiler always ends by moving `d7` to `d0` in your tests, but I bet there are other cases in which it won't.

Comment: Correct, Nate. Completely unreliable unless there’s some documentation on it.

Comment: Nate, I’ve just had a look at the latest 2021 “Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)” document and there’s still no support for DP constraints. So if your “P” constraint works that’s just as unreliable as my use of D7.

Comment: Well, my impression is that `P` is a modifier that's used internally by the compiler, though not documented for external use.  So at least someone has taken some effort to make it consistently do what it claims, even if it may change in the future (probably unlikely).  But I think D7 works entirely by chance.  Neither is great but it seems to me that `P` is less bad.

Comment: Agreed. See the additional para in my answer.